# Repair all tables in one go

Tags: mysql, sql

How to check all the tables in the database in one go?

Rather than typing the query `check table ''tablename'';` for all the tables one by one.

Is there any simple command like `check all` or anything like that?

Answer (score 183):

from command line you can use:

```
mysqlcheck -A --auto-repair
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlcheck.html

Answer (score 122):

The command is this:

```
mysqlcheck -u root -p --auto-repair --check --all-databases
```

You must supply the password when asked,

or you can run this one but it's not recommended because the password is written in clear text:

```
mysqlcheck -u root --password=THEPASSWORD --auto-repair --check --all-databases
```

Comment: mysqlcheck -u root -p --auto-repair --check --optimize --all-databases
Error:  mysqlcheck doesn't support multiple contradicting commands

Comment: If you get the contradicting commands error, take out the --optimize option.

Comment: i guess you have to use one and only one of these options: auto-repair, check or optimize. I used auto-repair only and worked

Comment: I tried what you said but I get:

mysqlcheck: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) when trying to connect

and I know I am using the correct password.

Answer (score 29):

Use following query to print `REPAIR` SQL statments for all tables inside a database:

```
select concat('REPAIR TABLE ', table_name, ';') from information_schema.tables 
where table_schema='mydatabase';
```

After that copy all the queries and execute it on `mydatabase`.

Note: replace `mydatabase` with desired DB name

Answer (score 14):

No need to type in the password, just use any one of these commands (self explanatory):

```
mysqlcheck --all-databases -a #analyze
mysqlcheck --all-databases -r #repair
mysqlcheck --all-databases -o #optimize
```

Answer (score 9):

The following command worked for me using the command prompt (As an Administrator) in Windows:

```
mysqlcheck -u root -p -A --auto-repair
```

*Run mysqlcheck with the root user, prompt for a password, check all databases, and auto-repair any corrupted tables.*

Answer (score 4):

If corrupted tables remain after

```
mysqlcheck -A --auto-repair
```

try

```
mysqlcheck -A --auto-repair --use-frm
```

Comment: what does the -use-frm do?

Comment: --use-frm

For repair operations on MyISAM tables, get the table structure from the data dictionary so that the table can be repaired even if the .MYI header is corrupted.

(cf. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlcheck.html#option_mysqlcheck_use-frm )

Answer (score 3):

There is no default command to do that, but you may create a procedure to do the job.
It will iterate through rows of `information_schema` and call `REPAIR TABLE 'tablename';` for every row. `CHECK TABLE` is not yet supported for prepared statements. Here's the example (replace MYDATABASE with your database name):

```
CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost'
PROCEDURE MYDATABASE.repair_all()
BEGIN
  DECLARE endloop INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE tableName char(100);
  DECLARE rCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT `TABLE_NAME` FROM `information_schema`.`TABLES` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`=DATABASE();
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET endloop=1;

  OPEN rCursor;
  FETCH rCursor INTO tableName;

  WHILE endloop = 0 DO
    SET @sql = CONCAT("REPAIR TABLE `", tableName, "`");
    PREPARE statement FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE statement;

    FETCH rCursor INTO tableName;
  END WHILE;

  CLOSE rCursor;
END
```

Answer (score 1):

I like this for a simple check from the shell:

```
mysql -p<password> -D<database> -B -e "SHOW TABLES LIKE 'User%'" \
| awk 'NR != 1 {print "CHECK TABLE "$1";"}' \
| mysql -p<password> -D<database>
```

Comment: you can use `mysql -ss` to make column names omitted from output - this would allow to remove `NR != 1` from your code

Answer (score 1):

for plesk hosts, one of these should do: (both do the same)

```
mysqlrepair -uadmin -p$(cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow) -A
# or
mysqlcheck -uadmin -p$(cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow) --repair -A
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need user name and password:

```
mysqlcheck -A --auto-repair -uroot -p
```

You will be prompted for password.

```
mysqlcheck -A --auto-repair -uroot -p{{password here}}
```

If you want to put in cron, BUT your password will be visible in plain text!