# Repetitive mysqld.exe crashes - OS error number 995 & mysql Exception 0x80000003

Tags: mysql, xampp

In the last few weeks our mysql DB has been crashing randomly. -

I have ran a check against all the databases for corruption but all are OK.

EDIT 2016.01.14 - The error that keeps popping up commonly is the following -

```
InnoDB: Database page corruption on disk or a failed
        InnoDB: file read of page 0.
```

Although, the 'File Read Page' is always different, the last time it was Zero, but before that it was 4500.

**A little background.**

- Been running Xampp for over a year without a problem
- We have Applications constantly inserting data into MYSQL from lots of data sources, this is 24/7.

  - Apart from the above applications, nothing else runs around the time of the crash, I have also checked the system logs to see if anything sticks out but it doesn't.
- Two weeks ago, we moved to another server with better spec, the old server was cloned and place on the new one.
- Nothing has been altered in DB or new tables added.
- Within a week, mysql started to produce errors.

**The new server specs are as follows -**

Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard - Running Service Pack 1

Proccessor: Intel(R) Xeon(R) @ 3.3ghz 2x Dual processor

8GB Ram

64Bit OS (Same as old server)

MySQL Version: 5.6.20

PHP Version 5.5.15

**Here are the recent error logs -**

```
     *************MYSQL ERROR LOG*****************



//////////////////////////////////*********************
         ERROR on 2016-01-05
******************///////////////////////

            InnoDB: The error means that the I/O operation has been aborted
            InnoDB: because of either a thread exit or an application request.
            InnoDB: Retry attempt is made.
            2016-01-05 08:42:52 cc8  InnoDB: Operating system error number 995 in a file operation.
            InnoDB: The error means that the I/O operation has been aborted
            InnoDB: because of either a thread exit or an application request.
            InnoDB: Retry attempt is made.
            2016-01-05 08:42:52 cc8  InnoDB: Operating system error number 995 in a file operation.
            InnoDB: The error means that the I/O operation has been aborted
            InnoDB: because of either a thread exit or an application request.
            InnoDB: Retry attempt is made.
            2016-01-05 08:42:53 cc8  InnoDB: Operating system error number 995 in a file operation.
            InnoDB: The error means that the I/O operation has been aborted
            InnoDB: because of either a thread exit or an application request.
            InnoDB: Retry attempt is made.
            2016-01-05 08:42:53 cc8  InnoDB: Operating system error number 995 in a file operation.
            InnoDB: The error means that the I/O operation has been aborted
            InnoDB: because of either a thread exit or an application request.
            InnoDB: Retry attempt is made.


//////////////////////////////////*********************        
        Error- 2015-12-22
********************************///////////////////////////

        2015-12-22 16:46:02 12d4 InnoDB: uncompressed page, stored checksum in field1 1169359801, calculated checksums for field1: crc32 4003191917, innodb 1169359801, none 3735928559, stored checksum in field2 4049981449, calculated checksums for field2: crc32 4003191917, innodb 587193584, none 3735928559, page LSN 128 4137924960, low 4 bytes of LSN at page end 4137853843, page number (if stored to page already) 0, space id (if created with >= MySQL-4.1.1 and stored already) 252
        InnoDB: Page may be a file space header page
        InnoDB: Database page corruption on disk or a failed
        InnoDB: file read of page 0.
        InnoDB: You may have to recover from a backup.
        InnoDB: It is also possible that your operating
        InnoDB: system has corrupted its own file cache
        InnoDB: and rebooting your computer removes the
        InnoDB: error.
        InnoDB: If the corrupt page is an index page
        InnoDB: you can also try to fix the corruption
        InnoDB: by dumping, dropping, and reimporting
        InnoDB: the corrupt table. You can use CHECK
        InnoDB: TABLE to scan your table for corruption.
        InnoDB: See also http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
        InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
        InnoDB: Database page corruption on disk or a failed
        InnoDB: file read of page 0.
        InnoDB: You may have to recover from a backup.
        2015-12-22 16:46:02 12d4 InnoDB: Page dump in ascii and hex (16384 bytes): // Lots of binary here ..

        InnoDB: End of page dump
        2015-12-22 16:46:03 12d4 InnoDB: uncompressed page, stored checksum in field1 1169359801, calculated checksums for field1: crc32 4003191917, innodb 1169359801, none 3735928559, stored checksum in field2 4049981449, calculated checksums for field2: crc32 4003191917, innodb 587193584, none 3735928559, page LSN 128 4137924960, low 4 bytes of LSN at page end 4137853843, page number (if stored to page already) 0, space id (if created with >= MySQL-4.1.1 and stored already) 252
        InnoDB: Page may be a file space header page
        InnoDB: Database page corruption on disk or a failed
        InnoDB: file read of page 0.
        InnoDB: You may have to recover from a backup.
        InnoDB: It is also possible that your operating
        InnoDB: system has corrupted its own file cache
        InnoDB: and rebooting your computer removes the
        InnoDB: error.
        InnoDB: If the corrupt page is an index page
        InnoDB: you can also try to fix the corruption
        InnoDB: by dumping, dropping, and reimporting
        InnoDB: the corrupt table. You can use CHECK
        InnoDB: TABLE to scan your table for corruption.
        InnoDB: See also http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
        InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
        InnoDB: Error: Unable to read tablespace 252 page no 0 into the buffer pool after 100 attempts
        InnoDB: The most probable cause of this error may be that the table has been corrupted.
        InnoDB: You can try to fix this problem by using innodb_force_recovery.
        InnoDB: Please see reference manual for more details.
        InnoDB: Aborting...
        2015-12-22 16:46:03 12d4  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 4820 in file buf0buf.cc line 2641
        InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
        InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
        InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
        InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
        InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
        InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
        InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
        16:46:03 UTC - mysqld got exception 0x80000003 ;
        This could be because you hit a bug.
         It is also possible that this binary
        or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt,
         improperly built,
        or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.

        We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
        diagnose the problem, 
        but since we have already crashed, 
        something is definitely wrong and this may 
        fail.

        key_buffer_size=16777216
        read_buffer_size=262144
        max_used_connections=107
        max_threads=151
        thread_count=5
        connection_count=5

        It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
        key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 133778 K  bytes 
        of memory


        Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.


        Thread pointer: 0x22020238
        Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
        where mysqld died.
         If you see no messages after this, something went
        terribly wrong...
        50a500 
           mysqld.exe!my_thread_name()
        74392d    mysqld.exe!my_mb_ctype_mb()
        5ecdb6   
         mysqld.exe!?my_aes_create_key@@YAXPBEIPAEW4my_aes_opmode@@@Z()
        61d611  
          mysqld.exe!?my_aes_create_key@@YAXPBEIPAEW4my_aes_opmode@@@Z()
        647350  
          mysqld.exe!?my_aes_create_key@@YAXPBEIPAEW4my_aes_opmode@@@Z()
        6492fa   
         mysqld.exe!?my_aes_create_key@@YAXPBEIPAEW4my_aes_opmode@@@Z()
        649383  
          mysqld.exe!?my_aes_create_key@@YAXPBEIPAEW4my_aes_opmode@@@Z()
        6493b3  
          mysqld.exe!?my_aes_create_key@@YAXPBEIPAEW4my_aes_opmode@@@Z()
        64945d  
          mysqld.exe!?my_aes_create_key@@YAXPBEIPAEW4my_aes_opmode@@@Z()
        6495cb  
          mysqld.exe!?my_aes_create_key@@YAXPBEIPAEW4my_aes_opmode@@@Z()
        5d48e3  
          mysqld.exe!?my_aes_create_key@@YAXPBEIPAEW4my_aes_opmode@@@Z()
        53f011  
          mysqld.exe!?my_aes_create_key@@YAXPBEIPAEW4my_aes_opmode@@@Z()
        2be48e  
          mysqld.exe!?ha_write_row@handler@@QAEHPAE@Z()
        3d8d10   
         mysqld.exe!?write_record@@YAHPAVTHD@@PAUTABLE@@PAVCOPY_INFO@@2@Z()
        3df599   
         mysqld.exe!?mysql_insert@@YA_NPAVTHD@@PAUTABLE_LIST@@AAV?$List@VItem@@@@AAV?$List@V?$List@VItem@@@@@@22W4enum_duplicates@@_N@Z()
        2ecdf5    
        mysqld.exe!?mysql_execute_command@@YAHPAVTHD@@@Z()
        2ef81e    
        mysqld.exe!?mysql_parse@@YAXPAVTHD@@PADIPAVParser_state@@@Z()
        2f06f8   
         mysqld.exe!?dispatch_command@@YA_NW4enum_server_command@@PAVTHD@@PADI@Z()
        2f135a   
         mysqld.exe!?do_command@@YA_NPAVTHD@@@Z()
        364e59    mysqld.exe!?do_handle_one_connection@@YAXPAVTHD@@@Z()
        364efd  
          mysqld.exe!handle_one_connection()
        6bb8cb    mysqld.exe!?my_aes_create_key@@YAXPBEIPAEW4my_aes_opmode@@@Z()
        510336  
          mysqld.exe!win_pthread_mutex_trylock()
        746c00    mysqld.exe!my_mb_ctype_mb()
        746c8a  
          mysqld.exe!my_mb_ctype_mb()
        7728338a    kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk()
        77c297f2  
          ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain()
        77c297c5 
           ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain()


        Trying to get some variables.
        Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
        Query (21e3387c): INSERT INTO 'WPM'(
        `Pos`, 
        `FileMod`, 
        `Duration`) VALUES (
        'IWM', 
        '2015-12-14 07:47:47 ',  
        0)Connection ID (thread ID): 3722
        Status: NOT_KILLED


        The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains

        information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
        2015-12-23 08:21:58 4920 
        [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
        2015-12-23 08:21:58 10c4 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
        2015-12-23 08:21:58 4920 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
        2015-12-23 08:21:58 4920 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
        2015-12-23 08:21:58 4920 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
        2015-12-23 08:21:58 4920 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
        2015-12-23 08:21:58 4920 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
        2015-12-23 08:21:58 4920 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
        2015-12-23 08:21:58 4920 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
        2015-12-23 08:21:58 4920 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
        2015-12-23 08:21:58 4920 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
        2015-12-23 08:21:58 4920 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 553893690098
        2015-12-23 08:21:58 4920 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
        2015-12-23 08:21:58 4920 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
        2015-12-23 08:21:58 4920 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
        2015-12-23 08:21:59 4920 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
        2015-12-23 08:21:59 4920 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
        InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 553893828751
        InnoDB: 1 transaction(s) which must be rolled back or cleaned up
        InnoDB: in total 151 row operations to undo
        InnoDB: Trx id counter is 152858880
        2015-12-23 08:22:00 4920 [Note] InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
        InnoDB: Progress in percent: 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
        InnoDB: Apply batch completed
        2015-12-23 08:22:00 4920 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
        InnoDB: Starting in background the rollback of uncommitted transactions
        2015-12-23 08:22:00 2c4  InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id 152858375, 151 rows to undo
        2015-12-23 08:22:00 4920 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
        2015-12-23 08:22:00 4920 [Note] InnoDB: Rollback of trx with id 152858375 completed
        2015-12-23 08:22:00 2c4  InnoDB: Rollback of non-prepared transactions completed
        2015-12-23 08:22:00 4920 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.20 started; log sequence number 553893828751
        2015-12-23 08:22:00 4920 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
        2015-12-23 08:22:00 4920 [Note] IPv6 is available.
        2015-12-23 08:22:00 4920 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
        2015-12-23 08:22:00 4920 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
        2015-12-23 08:22:00 4920 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 11 events
        2015-12-23 08:22:00 4920 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
        Version: '5.6.20'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
        2015-12-23 08:24:07 5736 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
        2015-12-23 08:24:07 fc8 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
        2015-12-23 08:24:07 5736 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
        2015-12-23 08:24:07 5736 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
        2015-12-23 08:24:07 5736 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
        2015-12-23 08:24:07 5736 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
        2015-12-23 08:24:07 5736 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
        2015-12-23 08:24:07 5736 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
        2015-12-23 08:24:07 5736 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
        2015-12-23 08:24:07 5736 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
        2015-12-23 08:24:07 5736 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
        2015-12-23 08:24:07 5736 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 553896050587
        2015-12-23 08:24:07 5736 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
        2015-12-23 08:24:07 5736 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
        2015-12-23 08:24:07 5736 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
        2015-12-23 08:24:07 5736 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
        2015-12-23 08:24:07 5736 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
        InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 553896774958
        2015-12-23 08:24:07 5736 [Note] InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
        InnoDB: Progress in percent: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
        InnoDB: Apply batch completed


//////////////////////////////////*********************
Error on 2016-01-08
********************////////////////////////
    2016-01-08 00:00:14 1584 InnoDB: uncompressed page, stored checksum in field1 1299653197, calculated checksums for field1: crc32 90466284, innodb 1299653197, none 3735928559, stored checksum in field2 341870525, calculated checksums for field2: crc32 90466284, innodb 3590763946, none 3735928559, page LSN 129 3920058837, low 4 bytes of LSN at page end 3920015931, page number (if stored to page already) 75791, space id (if created with >= MySQL-4.1.1 and stored already) 0
    InnoDB: Page may be an update undo log page
    InnoDB: Database page corruption on disk or a failed
    InnoDB: file read of page 75791.
    InnoDB: You may have to recover from a backup.
    InnoDB: It is also possible that your operating
    InnoDB: system has corrupted its own file cache
    InnoDB: and rebooting your computer removes the
    InnoDB: error.
    InnoDB: If the corrupt page is an index page
    InnoDB: you can also try to fix the corruption
    InnoDB: by dumping, dropping, and reimporting
    InnoDB: the corrupt table. You can use CHECK
    InnoDB: TABLE to scan your table for corruption.
    InnoDB: See also http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
    InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
    InnoDB: Ending processing because of a corrupt database page.
    2016-01-08 00:00:14 1584  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 5508 in file buf0buf.cc line 4195
    InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
    InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
    InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
    InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
    InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
    InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
    InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
    00:00:14 UTC - mysqld got exception 0x80000003 ;
    This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
    or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
    or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
    We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
    diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
    something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

    key_buffer_size=16777216
    read_buffer_size=262144
    max_used_connections=113
    max_threads=151
    thread_count=5
    connection_count=4
    It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
    key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 133778 K  bytes of memory
    Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

    Thread pointer: 0x0
    Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
    where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
    terribly wrong...
    116a500    mysqld.exe!my_thread_name()
    13a392d    mysqld.exe!my_mb_ctype_mb()
    12c7aa2    mysqld.exe!?my_aes_create_key@@YAXPBEIPAEW4my_aes_opmode@@@Z()
    12c82ad    mysqld.exe!?my_aes_create_key@@YAXPBEIPAEW4my_aes_opmode@@@Z()
    1225a72    mysqld.exe!?my_aes_create_key@@YAXPBEIPAEW4my_aes_opmode@@@Z()
    11d423b    mysqld.exe!?my_aes_create_key@@YAXPBEIPAEW4my_aes_opmode@@@Z()
    11d4694    mysqld.exe!?my_aes_create_key@@YAXPBEIPAEW4my_aes_opmode@@@Z()
    11d548a    mysqld.exe!?my_aes_create_key@@YAXPBEIPAEW4my_aes_opmode@@@Z()
    11b147d    mysqld.exe!?my_aes_create_key@@YAXPBEIPAEW4my_aes_opmode@@@Z()
    11b167d    mysqld.exe!?my_aes_create_key@@YAXPBEIPAEW4my_aes_opmode@@@Z()
    7728338a    kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk()
    77c297f2    ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain()
    77c297c5    ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain()
    The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
    information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
    InnoDB: Warning: a long semaphore wait:
    --Thread 6764 has waited at trx0undo.cc line 1778 for 29770.00 seconds the semaphore:
    Mutex at 1B4F60EC created file trx0rseg.cc line 196, lock var 1
    waiters flag 1
    InnoDB: ###### Starts InnoDB Monitor for 30 secs to print diagnostic info:
    InnoDB: Pending preads 0, pwrites 0
```

**Here is the mysql.ini settings file (If this helps)**

```
# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
port= 3306
socket = "C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
basedir = "C:/xampp/mysql" 
tmpdir = "C:/xampp/tmp" 
datadir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"
pid_file = "mysql.pid"
# enable-named-pipe
key_buffer = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
log_error = "mysql_error.log"


# Change here for bind listening
# bind-address="127.0.0.1" 
# bind-address = ::1          # for ipv6

# Where do all the plugins live
plugin_dir = "C:/xampp/mysql/lib/plugin/" 

# Don't listen on a TCP/IP port at all. This can be a security enhancement,
# if all processes that need to connect to mysqld run on the same host.
# All interaction with mysqld must be made via Unix sockets or named pipes.
# Note that using this option without enabling named pipes on Windows
# (via the "enable-named-pipe" option) will render mysqld useless!
# 
# commented in by lampp security
#skip-networking
skip-federated

# Replication Master Server (default)
# binary logging is required for replication
# log-bin deactivated by default since XAMPP 1.4.11
#log-bin=mysql-bin

# required unique id between 1 and 2^32 - 1
# defaults to 1 if master-host is not set
# but will not function as a master if omitted
server-id   = 1

# Replication Slave (comment out master section to use this)
#
# To configure this host as a replication slave, you can choose between
# two methods :
#
# 1) Use the CHANGE MASTER TO command (fully described in our manual) -
#    the syntax is:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST=<host>, MASTER_PORT=<port>,
#    MASTER_USER=<user>, MASTER_PASSWORD=<password> ;
#
#    where you replace <host>, <user>, <password> by quoted strings and
#    <port> by the master's port number (3306 by default).
#
#    Example:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='125.564.12.1', MASTER_PORT=3306,
#    MASTER_USER='joe', MASTER_PASSWORD='secret';
#
# OR
#
# 2) Set the variables below. However, in case you choose this method, then
#    start replication for the first time (even unsuccessfully, for example
#    if you mistyped the password in master-password and the slave fails to
#    connect), the slave will create a master.info file, and any later
#    change in this file to the variables' values below will be ignored and
#    overridden by the content of the master.info file, unless you shutdown
#    the slave server, delete master.info and restart the slaver server.
#    For that reason, you may want to leave the lines below untouched
#    (commented) and instead use CHANGE MASTER TO (see above)
#
# required unique id between 2 and 2^32 - 1
# (and different from the master)
# defaults to 2 if master-host is set
# but will not function as a slave if omitted
#server-id       = 2
#
# The replication master for this slave - required
#master-host     =   <hostname>
#
# The username the slave will use for authentication when connecting
# to the master - required
#master-user     =   <username>
#
# The password the slave will authenticate with when connecting to
# the master - required
#master-password =   <password>
#
# The port the master is listening on.
# optional - defaults to 3306
#master-port     =  <port>
#
# binary logging - not required for slaves, but recommended
#log-bin=mysql-bin


# Point the following paths to different dedicated disks
#tmpdir = "C:/xampp/tmp"
#log-update = /path-to-dedicated-directory/hostname

# Uncomment the following if you are using BDB tables
#bdb_cache_size = 4M
#bdb_max_lock = 10000

# Comment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
#skip-innodb
innodb_data_home_dir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"
#innodb_log_arch_dir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"
## You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
## of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2M
## Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
innodb_log_file_size = 5M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50

## UTF 8 Settings
#init-connect=\'SET NAMES utf8\'
#collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci
#character_set_server=utf8
#skip-character-set-client-handshake
#character_sets-dir="C:/xampp/mysql/share/charsets"

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates

[isamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

I simply have no idea what to do, I have no experience in the technical side to troubleshooting Mysql. I have looked on the MYsql site, are apparently error code 995 is a known bug, it was meant to be fixed, but I read that it never got pushed into the build.

If you need any more info please ask!

Comment: This looks like a known bug in MySQL 5.0 for InnoDB when using a large database. See: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=3139. You should look into updating MySQL.

Comment: Already seen it.. The i refered to it in the last paragraph of my question.

Comment: You did not include a link, which is why I added the comment. It looks like it was fixed in MySQL 5.1.42 and should also be fixed in later versions. If nobody has a work around for this bug, then upgrading is your best option.

Comment: Did you change versions of MySQL when you upgraded the hardware?   `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%version%';`  `MySQL Version: mysqlnd 5.0.11` may be referring to the version of that API.

Comment: Hm, I ran the phpInfo() command to get the version number of mysql, but I have just ran your command "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%version%';" and it says my version is 5.6.20.

Comment: That might be due to your version of PHP. I assume you're using PHP 5.3 if you returned mysqlnd 5.0.11 from phpinfo. You may need to upgrade your PHP to 5.4 or later. https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/php-mysqlnd/

Comment: Just checked, its running Php 5.5

Comment: No, the full server state was cloned.

Answer (score 3):

InnoDB deliberately crashes MySQL if it reads a page from "disk" (might come from RAM though if the relevant blocks are in OS cache) and the checksum mismatches with the one in the page header. This is what's happening to you.

Reasons could be:

- If you're not using ECC ram you might just have some corrupted data in OS cache. Rebooting the server will clear the cache and you can get some ECC ram to prevent it happening. (less likely)
- On disk corruption (more likely):

  - If you're lucky the corruption is on index pages and you can fully recover by doing a innodb_recovery (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html)
  - If the corruption is on data page you most certainly will lose data but you still should be able to recover most of the information using the same method.

In such cases I would just restore from backup if that's possible. The other error you pasted also indicates system level I/O issues so I would look into it soon before it crashes completely.

Comment: Already tried to recover the InnoDB following the guide on MySql's website. This didn't seem to fix it.

Comment: In short what @Károly-Nagy means is that your storage or main memory are about to die: install a brand new hardware with the last backup from mysqldump.

Answer (score 1):

I believe some pages in Innodb tablespace got corrupted..
First backup your DB!

First suggestion would be to run check table using this command:

```
mysqlcheck -A --auto-repair
```

Reference: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582832/repair-all-tables-in-one-go)

Add the following line below the mysqld section in the mysql config file (my.ini) and restart both the apache and mysql service afterwards.

```
innodb_force_recovery = 1
```

For your information: [read this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html)

Note: Innodb becomes read only for data operations when running in innodb_force_recovery mode

If this is not working, my second suggestion would be to decrease the innodb_buffer_pool_size and convert some "heavey loading" tables into MyISAM:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE=MYISAM
```

Although you increased the specs of your machine, due to high usage of your DB table can still cause a problem.

(Please update me and which you good luck!)

Comment: Tried your ideas but it has since crashed. Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: @Dan so what's the status now? How did it crashed, anything I can help?

Comment: Everything the same really as the errors in my question.