# mysqldump: Got error: 1146: Table ' myDatabase.table' doesn't exist when using LOCK TABLES

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to get dump of my database:

```
mysqldump myDatabase > myDatabase.sql
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
mysqldump: Got error: 1146: Table 'myDatabase.table' doesn't exist when using LOCK TABLES
```

When I go to mysql:

```
 mysql -u admin -p
```

I query for the tables:

```
show tables;
```

I see the table. but when I query for that particular table:

```
 select * from table;
```

I get the same error:

```
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'myDatabase.table' doesn't exist
```

I tried to repair:

```
mysqlcheck -u admin -p --auto-repair --check --all-databases
```

but get the same error:

```
Error    : Table 'myDatase.table' doesn't exist
```

Why I'm getting this error or how can I fix this error?

I'll really appreciate your help

Comment: are you sure that in  the table  name  there are not hiidden char ..eg:   char fo table name length ..

Comment: It could be a filesystem permission problem, database corruption or failed migration of your database from on OS to a different one (e.g. macOS/window to linux)? One thing you could try is [Repair all tables in one go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582832/repair-all-tables-in-one-go). If it is an InnoDB table, then it might be more complex to solve the problem.

Comment: take a look at this  also http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/107429/error-1146-42s02-table-db-tablename-doesnt-exist

Comment: @scaisEdge `mysqldump` should use the correct naming, it might be more a configuration or corruption problem. E.g. moving the config and/or database from a case insensitive filesystem to a case sensitive one.

Comment: @scaisEdge, I have updated my question.

Comment: On which OS you your run you mysql installation? Did you migrate the data from an other OS? What are the values for `lower_case_file` `lower_case table_names`? Is that table a `InnoDB` or a `MyISAM` table?

Comment: @t.niese, yes, this database was in another box. How do I get the values for lower_case_file and lower_case table_names?

Answer (score 17):

For me the problem was resolved by going to */var/lib/mysql* (or wherever you raw database files are stored) and deleting the .frm file for the table that the errors says does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

I had an issue with doing mysqldump on the server, I realized that tables that if that tables were not used for longer time, then I do not need those (old applications that were shutdown).

**The case:** *Cannot do backup with mysqldump, there are tables that are not needed anymore and are corrupted*

At first I get the list of corrupted tables

```
mysqlcheck --repair --all-databases -u root -p"${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}" > repair.log
```

Then I analyze the log with a Python script that takes it at stdin (save as ex. analyze.py and do cat repair.log| python3 analyze.py)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import re
import sys

lines = sys.stdin.read().split("\n")
tables = []

for line in lines:
    if "Error" in line:
        matches = re.findall('Table \'([A-Za-z0-9_.]+)\' doesn', line)
        tables.append(matches[0])

print('{', end='')
print(",".join(tables), end='')
print('}', end='')
```

You will get a list of corrupted databases.

Do an export with mysqldump

```
mysqldump -h 127.0.0.1 -u root  -p"${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}"  -P 3306  --skip-lock-tables --add-drop-table --add-drop-database --add-drop-trigger  --all-databases --ignore-table={table1,table2,table3 - here is output of the previous command} > dump.sql
```

Turn off the database, move /var/lib/mysql to /var/lib/mysql-backup, start database.

On a clean database just import the dump.sql, restart database, enjoy an instance without corrupted tables.

Answer (score 1):

I recently came across a similar issue on an Ubuntu server that was upgraded to 16.04 LTS. In the process, MySQL was replaced with MariaDB and apparently the old database couldn't be automatically converted to a compatible format. The installer moved the original database from `/var/lib/mysql` to `/var/lib/mysql-5.7`.

Interestingly, the original table structure was present under the new `/var/lib/mysql/[database_name]` in the `.frm` files. The new ibdata file was 12M and the 2 logfiles were 48M, from which I concluded, that the data *must* be there, but later I found that initializing a completely empty database results in similar sizes, so that's not indicative.

I installed 16.04 LTS on a VirtualBox, installed MySQL on it, then copied the `mysql-5.7` directory and renamed it to `mysql`. Started the server and dumped everything with `mysqldump`. Deleted the `/var/lib/mysql` on the original server, initialized a new one with `mysql_install_db` and imported the sql file from mysqldump.

Note: I was not the one who originally did the system upgrade, so there may be a few details missing, but the symptoms were similar to yours, so maybe this could help.

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to @Krzysztof Wesołowski's answer (can't comment yet), here's a bash oneliner to get all the tables that doesn't exist:

```
mysqlcheck --repair --all-databases | grep "doesn't exist" | awk '{print $4}' | sed "s/'//g"
```